# How does this code work to Find the next highest power of 2 for any given number

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

How does this code work to **Find the next highest power of 2 for any given number [>1] for 32 bit integer?**

```
n--;
n = n | n>>1;
n = n | n>>2;
n = n | n>>4;
n = n | n>>8;
n = n | n>>16;
n++;
```

Comment: Is it homework/interview question?

Comment: I would say that it doesn't find the next highest power of 2 for ANY given number >1, because inputs that are already powers of 2 return themselves instead of the next power of 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sequence of shifts and bitwise-ors guarantees a number that consists of all `1`s, which is one less than a power-of-2.  Adding 1 to it gives a power-of-2.

The initial decrement by 1 is to make it work for values of `n` that are already powers-of-2.

(Obviously, this code doesn't work if `n` is originally `0`.)

Comment: @hatchet It works for 1, same as for 2, 4, etc. Decrement ~> 0; shifts and `|` ~> 0; Increment ~> 1.

Comment: @DanielFischer - but the power of two after 1 (2^0) is 2 (2^1), not 1. That algorithm will dec 1 to 0, then all the right shifts and or's will still result in 0, then the inc results in 1 (which is not correct).

Comment: @hatchet Same as with 2, 4 etc., which will also come out to the same value (4 ~>[decrement] 3 ~>[shift] 3 ~>[increment] 4). "Next highest" in the implementation of the function means "the smallest power of 2 not smaller than the argument". It's ambiguous, but in the interpretation of the implementation, it works for all positive `n` which don't overflow (for `int32_t`, the maximal value where it works is 2^30).

Comment: @DanielFischer - I understand your point now. Although for inputs that are already powers of 2, that is a confusing definition of "next highest". When I see the word "next", I think "subsequent" or "following" in order.

Comment: @hatchet I agree. But we can't know whether the formulation is due to the author of the code or the OP, so we can't know whom to blame.

Answer (score 1):

The decrement will make the case 2 ^ n to give the result 2 ^ n instead of 2 ^ (n + 1). It does not correspond to the increment at the end.

The part between decrement and increment actually tries to fill up all the bit that is less significant than the currently most significant bit that is 1. The highest bit that is 1 will gradually propagate after each line and will fill up all the less significant bits by the last line.

The increment is to get to the result of the next highest power of 2.